# svg rotation matrix inverse matrix

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, vue.js

I am a Japanese beginner web developer.

I am not good at English sorry.

I made a sample code that you can move or resize rect.

I am using vue.js and svg.

```
<template>

  <div class="rotate-area">

    <div class="rotate">

      <svg width="608" height="408" viewBox="0 0 608 408" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg" ref="svg" @mousemove="mouseMove" @mouseup="mouseUp">

        <g stroke-width="1" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" class="layer" :transform="rotate">

          <g fill-opacity="1">

            <rect stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0" :x="masterX" :y="masterY" :width="width" :height="height" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'master')"></rect>

            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="leftTopX" :y="leftTopY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'leftTop')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="rightTopX" :y="rightTopY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'rightTop')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="rightBottomX" :y="rightBottomY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'rightBottom')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="leftBottomX" :y="leftBottomY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'leftBottom')"></rect>

          </g>

        </g>

      </svg>

    </div>

    <input type="number" v-model="angle">

  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class Rotate extends Vue {

  width = 150
  widthBefore = 150
  height = 150
  heightBefore = 150

  masterX = 24
  masterXBefore = 24
  masterY = 25
  masterYBefore = 25

  leftTopX = 20.5
  leftTopXBefore = 20.5
  leftTopY = 20.5
  leftTopYBefore = 20.5

  rightTopX = 170.5
  rightTopXBefore = 170.5
  rightTopY = 20.5
  rightTopYBefore = 20.5

  rightBottomX = 170.5
  rightBottomXBefore = 170.5
  rightBottomY = 172.5
  rightBottomYBefore = 172.5

  leftBottomX = 20.5
  leftBottomXBefore = 20.5
  leftBottomY = 172.5
  leftBottomYBefore = 172.5

  angle = 0

  mouseDownState = false
  mouseDownType = ""
  pointStart = {
    x: 0,
    y : 0
  }

  get middleVector() {
    return { 
      x : (this.leftTopX + this.rightTopX) / 2 ,
      y : (this.leftTopY + this.leftBottomY) / 2
    }
  }

  get rotate() {
    return "rotate(" + this.angle + "," + this.middleVector.x + "," + this.middleVector.y + ")";
  }

  public select(event : MouseEvent , mouseDownType){
    this.mouseDownState = true
    this.mouseDownType = mouseDownType
    this.pointStart.x = event.clientX
    this.pointStart.y = event.clientY
  }

  public mouseMove(event : MouseEvent){
    if(this.mouseDownState){

      let moveDistance = {
        x : event.clientX - this.pointStart.x,
        y : event.clientY - this.pointStart.y
      }

      if(this.mouseDownType=="master"){

        this.masterX = this.masterXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.masterY = this.masterYBefore +  moveDistance.y
        this.leftTopX = this.leftTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.leftTopY = this.leftTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.rightTopX = this.rightTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightTopY = this.rightTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.rightBottomX = this.rightBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightBottomY = this.rightBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.leftBottomX = this.leftBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.leftBottomY = this.leftBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y

      }else if (this.mouseDownType == "leftTop") {

        this.masterX = this.masterXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.masterY = this.masterYBefore +  moveDistance.y
        this.leftTopX = this.leftTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.leftTopY = this.leftTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.rightTopY = this.rightTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.leftBottomX = this.leftBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x

        this.width = this.widthBefore - moveDistance.x
        this.height = this.heightBefore - moveDistance.y

      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightTop") {

        this.masterY = this.masterYBefore +  moveDistance.y
        this.leftTopY = this.leftTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.rightTopX = this.rightTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightTopY = this.rightTopYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.rightBottomX = this.rightBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x

        this.width = this.widthBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.height = this.heightBefore - moveDistance.y

      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightBottom") {

        this.rightTopX = this.rightTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightBottomX = this.rightBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightBottomY = this.rightBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.leftBottomY = this.leftBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.width = this.widthBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.height = this.heightBefore + moveDistance.y

      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "leftBottom") {

        this.masterX = this.masterXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.leftTopX = this.leftTopXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.rightBottomY = this.rightBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.leftBottomX = this.leftBottomXBefore + moveDistance.x
        this.leftBottomY = this.leftBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y
        this.width = this.widthBefore - moveDistance.x
        this.height = this.heightBefore + moveDistance.y

      }
    }
  }

  mouseUp(){

    this.mouseDownState = false

    if(this.mouseDownType=="master"){
        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
        this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
        this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
        this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY
    }else if (this.mouseDownType == "leftTop") {

        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
        this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX

        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightTop") {

            this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
            this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
            this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
            this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
            this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX

            this.widthBefore = this.width
            this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightBottom") {

        this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
        this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY
        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if(this.mouseDownType == "leftBottom"){
        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY
        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height
      }
  }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Sorry that this code is not stylish and it's hard to read.

I have a problem here.

When you resize after you rotate it, the edge you grab and the cursor move doesn't match.

When the angle is 0 , it works properly.

I want to make the edge always follows the cursor.

I thought I have to inverse rotation matrix.

```
public mouseMove(event : MouseEvent){
    if(this.mouseDownState){

      let moveDistance = {
        x : event.clientX - this.pointStart.x,
        y : event.clientY - this.pointStart.y
      }

      moveDistance.x = Math.cos(this.angle) * (moveDistance.x - this.middleVector.x) + Math.sin(this.angle) * (moveDistance.y - this.middleVector.y) + this.middleVector.x 

      moveDistance.y = ***
```

Should I do something like this?

Though I am not good at math.

Someone help me please!!!(>___<)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct that your program rotates/resizes a rectangle when the user clicks on one of the corners and moves their mouse?
The logic should be something like the following:

```js
var centerX = ______; //whatever the center of the rect is
var centerY = ______; //whatever the center of the rect is

var rectangleWidth = ________; //initial width of rectangle;
var rectangleHeight = ________; //initial height of rectangle;

var scale = 1; //scale of shown image to original

var rectangleRotation = 0; //initally no rotation

var clickX;
var clickY;
var rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked //rotation of the rectangle at the time it is clicked
var clickScale; //scale of rectangle when clicked
var clickRotation; //angle of mouse to the rectangle's center
var clickDistance; //distance of mouse to center of rectangle

function mouseDown(mouseEvent) {
  //sets variables when a corner gets clicked
  clickX = mouseEvent.clientX;
  clickY = mouseEvent.clientY;
  rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked = rectangleRotzation;
  clickRotation = Math.atan(clickY / clickX);
  clickDistance = Math.sqrt((clickX - centerX) ** 2 + (clickY - centerY) ** 2)
  clickScale = scale;
}

function moveMouse(mouseEvent) {
  //run when you move the mouse after clicking on a corner
  //does the logic of resizing and rotation
  //resize
  var ratioToResize = Math.sqrt(((mouseEvent.clientX - centerX) ** 2 + (mouseEvent.clientY - centerY) ** 2)) / clickDistance
  scale = ratioToResize * clickScale;

  //rotation
  var angle = Math.atan((mouseEvent.clientY - centerY) / (mouseEvent.clientX - centerX))
  rectangleRotation = rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked + angle - clickRotation;
}

function mouseUp(mouseEvent) {
  
}
```

Here is a program to make a moving rectangle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="math.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    It's a moving rectangle!
    <div id = "rectangle" style = "background-color:#ff0000; position:absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top:100px; left: 100px">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        mousePressed=false;
        centerX = 400;  //whatever the center of the rect is
        centerY = 300;  //whatever the center of the rect is


    rectangleWidth = 400;  //initial width of rectangle;
    rectangleHeight = 300;  //initial height of rectangle;

    rectangleRotation = 0;  //initally no rotation
    rectangle = document.getElementById("rectangle");
    rectangle.style.top = (centerY-rectangleHeight/2)+'px';
    rectangle.style.left = (centerX-rectangleWidth/2)+'px';
    rectangle.style.width = rectangleWidth+'px';
    rectangle.style.height = rectangleHeight+'px';
    rectangle.style.transform = 'rotate('+rectangleRotation*180/Math.PI+'deg)';
    rectangle.onmousedown = mouseDown;
    document.onmouseup = mouseUp;
    document.onmousemove = moveMouse;

    clickX;
    clickY;
    rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked; //rotation of the rectangle at the time it is clicked
    clickWidth;  //width of rectangle when clicked
    clickHeight;  //height of rectangle when clicked
    clickRotation;  //angle of mouse to the rectangle's center
    clickDistance;  //distance of mouse to center of rectangle

    function mouseDown(mouseEvent) {
        //sets variables when a corner gets clicked
        mousePressed=true;
        rectangle.style.backgroundColor = '#0000ff';
        clickX=mouseEvent.clientX;
        clickY=mouseEvent.clientY;
        rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked = rectangleRotation;
        clickRotation = Math.atan2((mouseEvent.clientY-centerY),(mouseEvent.clientX-centerX))
        clickDistance = Math.sqrt((clickX-centerX)**2 + (clickY-centerY)**2);
        clickWidth = rectangleWidth;
        clickHeight = rectangleHeight;
    }
    function moveMouse(mouseEvent) {
        if(!mousePressed) {
        return 0;}
        //run when you move the mouse after clicking on a corner
        //does the logic of resizing and rotation
        rectangle.style.backgroundColor="#00ff00";
        //resize
        var ratioToResize = Math.sqrt(((mouseEvent.clientX-centerX)**2 + (mouseEvent.clientY-centerY)**2))/clickDistance
        rectangleWidth = ratioToResize*clickWidth;
        rectangleHeight = ratioToResize*clickHeight;

        //rotation
        var angle = Math.atan2((mouseEvent.clientY-centerY),(mouseEvent.clientX-centerX))
        rectangleRotation = rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked + angle - clickRotation;

        rectangle.style.top = (centerY-rectangleHeight/2)+'px';
        rectangle.style.left = (centerX-rectangleWidth/2)+'px';
        rectangle.style.width = rectangleWidth+'px';
        rectangle.style.height = rectangleHeight+'px';
        rectangle.style.transform = 'rotate('+rectangleRotation*180/Math.PI+'deg)';
    }

    function mouseUp(mouseEvent) {
        mousePressed=false;
        rectangle.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good morning!!! I am so sorry that my response is late. I have been slept. I will check the answer after I arrived my work. Thank you so muck!

Comment: Thank you. In my code , rotation only happens when you input number in the input tag at the bottom.

Comment: This is great code , thank you so much. But I want to move the whole rect which is  "master" pattern in my code. And I want the edge diagonal not to move when resizing it. For example , when you resized it by pulling leftTop , the position of rightBottom shouldn't move.

Comment: But very good idea. Thank you so much. I can translate for my code.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer , but I got a different problem , if you can , please check my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176195/svg-rotation-and-move-with-vue-js