# svg rotation and move with vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, vue.js

I want to rotate and move svg rectangle by dragging it.

[svg rotation matrix inverse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151429/svg-rotation-matrix-inverse-matrix)

Here is the question which I did yesterday.

And I got an idea from the answer.

Here is my new code.

```
<template>

  <div class="rotate-area">

    <div class="rotate">

      <svg width="608" height="408" viewBox="0 0 608 408" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg" ref="svg" @mousemove="mouseMove" @mouseup="mouseUp">

        <g stroke-width="1" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" class="layer" :transform="rotate">

          <g fill-opacity="1">

            <rect stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0" :x="masterX" :y="masterY" :width="width" :height="height" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'master')"></rect>

            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="leftTopX" :y="leftTopY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'leftTop')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="rightTopX" :y="rightTopY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'rightTop')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="rightBottomX" :y="rightBottomY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'rightBottom')"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffffff" :x="leftBottomX" :y="leftBottomY" width="7" height="7" @mousedown.self="select($event , 'leftBottom')"></rect>

          </g>

        </g>

      </svg>

    </div>

    <input type="number" v-model="angle">

  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class Rotate extends Vue {

  clickRotation = 0
  clickDistance = 0
  clickWidth = 0
  clickHeight = 0
  rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked = 0



  width = 150
  widthBefore = 150
  height = 150
  heightBefore = 150

  leftTopX = 20.5
  leftTopXBefore = 20.5
  leftTopY = 20.5
  leftTopYBefore = 20.5

  masterXBefore = this.masterX

  masterYBefore = this.masterY

  rightTopX = 170.5
  rightTopXBefore = 170.5
  rightTopY = 20.5
  rightTopYBefore = 20.5

  rightBottomX = 170.5
  rightBottomXBefore = 170.5
  rightBottomY = 172.5
  rightBottomYBefore = 172.5

  leftBottomX = 20.5
  leftBottomXBefore = 20.5
  leftBottomY = 172.5
  leftBottomYBefore = 172.5

  angle = 0

  mouseDownState = false
  mouseDownType = ""
  pointStart = {
    x: 0,
    y : 0
  }

  get masterX(){
    return this.leftTopX + 3.5
  }

  get masterY(){
    return this.leftTopY + 4.5
  }

  get middleVector() {
    return { 
      x : (this.leftTopX + this.rightTopX) / 2 ,
      y : (this.leftTopY + this.leftBottomY) / 2
    }
  }

  get rotate() {
    return "rotate(" + this.angle * 180 / Math.PI + "," + this.middleVector.x + "," + this.middleVector.y + ")";
  }

  public select(event : MouseEvent , mouseDownType){
    this.mouseDownState = true
    this.mouseDownType = mouseDownType
    this.pointStart.x = event.clientX
    this.pointStart.y = event.clientY

    this.rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked = this.angle;
    this.clickRotation = Math.atan2((event.clientY - this.middleVector.y), (event.clientX - this.middleVector.x))
    this.clickDistance = Math.sqrt((event.clientX - this.middleVector.x) ** 2 + (event.clientY - this.middleVector.y) ** 2)
    this.clickWidth = this.width;
    this.clickHeight = this.height;

  }

  public mouseMove(event : MouseEvent){
    if(this.mouseDownState){

      let moveDistance = {
        x : event.clientX - this.pointStart.x,
        y : event.clientY - this.pointStart.y
      }

      let ratioToResize = Math.sqrt(((event.clientX - this.middleVector.x) ** 2 + (event.clientY - this.middleVector.y) ** 2)) / this.clickDistance

      if(this.mouseDownType != "master"){
        this.width = ratioToResize * this.clickWidth;
        this.height = ratioToResize * this.clickHeight;
        let left = this.middleVector.x - this.width / 2;
        let right = this.middleVector.x + this.width / 2;
        let top = this.middleVector.y - this.height / 2;
        let bottom = this.middleVector.y + this.height / 2;

        if (this.mouseDownType == "leftTop") {

        this.leftTopX = left
        this.leftTopY = top
        this.rightTopY = top
        this.leftBottomX = left


      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightTop") {


        this.leftTopY = top
        this.rightTopX = right
        this.rightTopY = top
        this.rightBottomX = right


      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightBottom") {

        this.rightTopX = right
        this.rightBottomX = right
        this.rightBottomY = bottom
        this.leftBottomY = bottom
      } else if (this.mouseDownType == "leftBottom") {

        this.leftTopX = left
        this.rightBottomY = bottom
        this.leftBottomX = left
        this.leftBottomY = bottom

      }
      }else{
        let left = this.leftTopXBefore + moveDistance.x;
        let right = this.rightTopXBefore + moveDistance.x;
        let top = this.leftTopYBefore + moveDistance.y;
        let bottom = this.leftBottomYBefore + moveDistance.y;

        this.leftTopX = left
        this.leftTopY = top
        this.rightTopX = right
        this.rightTopY = top
        this.rightBottomX = right
        this.rightBottomY = bottom
        this.leftBottomX = left
        this.leftBottomY = bottom
      }



      var angle = Math.atan2((event.clientY - this.middleVector.y), (event.clientX - this.middleVector.x))
      this.angle = this.rotationOfRectangleWhenClicked + angle - this.clickRotation;

    }
  }

  mouseUp(){

    this.mouseDownState = false

    if(this.mouseDownType=="master"){
        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
        this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
        this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
        this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY
    }else if (this.mouseDownType == "leftTop") {

        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
        this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX

        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightTop") {

            this.masterYBefore = this.masterY
            this.leftTopYBefore = this.leftTopY
            this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
            this.rightTopYBefore = this.rightTopY
            this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX

            this.widthBefore = this.width
            this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if (this.mouseDownType == "rightBottom") {

        this.rightTopXBefore = this.rightTopX
        this.rightBottomXBefore = this.rightBottomX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY

        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height

      }else if(this.mouseDownType == "leftBottom"){
        this.masterXBefore = this.masterX
        this.leftTopXBefore = this.leftTopX
        this.rightBottomYBefore = this.rightBottomY
        this.leftBottomXBefore = this.leftBottomX
        this.leftBottomYBefore = this.leftBottomY

        this.widthBefore = this.width
        this.heightBefore = this.height
      }
  }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

It works almost properly.

But if I changed the position of whole area of svg , it works weird.

For example , like this.

```
<style lang="scss">

.rotate-area{

  position: absolute;
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  .rotate{
    position: absolute;
    top : 100px;
    left : 100px;
  } 

}

</style>
```

I don't no why this happens and I want to know how to fix it.

What I tried is to get ratio and multiply it to all the vector got by click or mouse move.

Like this.

```
mounted() {
      this.updateRatio();
    }

    protected updateRatio() {
      const { svg } = this.$refs;

      this.ratio = {
        x: 100 / svg.clientWidth,
        y: 100 / svg.clientHeight,
      };
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Please help me.(T___T)